# What are 'Article Influence' and 'CNCI' and how to obtain them?

Tags: publications, bibliometrics, evaluation-criteria

I've been asked about my *Article Influence* and my *Category Normalized Citation Impact (CNCI)*. I have several doubts regarding this:

1. Are they metrics that can be calculated for each article, or, on the contrary, do they refer to a single value per each researcher?
2. I haven't been able to determine what the 'Article Influence' actually refers to, or how to calculate it. Any clue?
3. Regarding the CNCI, I have found out that it is calculated and published by Clarivate (specifically, in [InCites](https://incites.clarivate.com/)). But, as far as I have been able to understand, there is NOT a CNCI for each article published by a researcher, but a CNCI for each category in which a certain author has published some work (in a certain period of time); and a global CNCI can also be calculated for a researcher (in a certain period of time). Is that so?

Comment: Does Article Influence Score refer to [this](https://jcr.help.clarivate.com/Content/glossary-article-influence-score.htm)? If so, it's a score calculated for journals and what you were asked seems akin to being asked about your individual impact factor. Perhaps it would be best to ask for clarification.

Comment: There is some info on article influence https://incites.help.clarivate.com/Content/Indicators-Handbook/ih-article-influence.htm and eigenfactor https://incites.help.clarivate.com/Content/Indicators-Handbook/ih-eigenfactor.htm?Highlight=eigenfactor, but both are only a metric on journal level, not for single articles, so I am unsure how that would matter for a person.

Comment: this might be usefull: https://mylibrary.sutd.edu.sg/sites/default/files/Research%20Guides/CNCI_SOP_20210218.pdf